# Logical error when trying to see if a number contains all 10 digits

Tags: python, set

Trying to use superset to see if a number has all 10 digits. This code should complete in 10 lines however it does not. Why is this the case? I am a beginner.

````
n = 1234567880
d = 1234567890
A = set(str(n))
C = set(str(d))
complete = True
print(A.issuperset(C))
while complete==True:
    if A.issuperset(C) == True:
        print(n)
        complete = False
    else:
        n = n + 1
        print(n)
else:
    print("completed")  ```
````

Comment: Adding 1 to `n` does not affect the set `A`.

Comment: If you want to see if a number `n` contains all digits, wouldn't `set(str(1234567890)) == set(str(n))` suffice?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @BenAgain! When you say "this code should complete in ten lines" that sounds like it might be a requirement for a homework assignment. If so, please mark the question with the `homework` tag so that the community can answer the question in a way that is most likely to help you learn! (If not, you can safely ignore this comment.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset `A` each iteration:

```
while complete:
    A = set(str(n))  # n has changed!
    if A == C:
        # ...
```

Also, `while-else` does probably not do what you expect it to. Since you never `break` the while loop manually, the `else` will always trigger. You could shorten your code:

```
import string

n = 1234567880
C = set(string.digits)
while True:
    print(n)
    if set(str(n)) == C:    
        break
    n += 1
print("completed")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `set(str(n)).issuperset("0123456789")`  as the while condition?

The issuperset() method returns True or False so it can be used as a condition directly (no need for == True)

```
n = 1234567880
while not set(str(n)).issuperset("0123456789"):
   print(n) 
   n += 1
print(n)
print("completed")

1234567880
1234567881
1234567882
1234567883
1234567884
1234567885
1234567886
1234567887
1234567888
1234567889
1234567890 
completed
```

*Note that you may not want to print inside the loop depending on the numbers you're going to start from because that could take a very long while to reach completion (could be more than a billion iterations)*

If what you're really looking for is a function to find the next number that has all digits, starting from n, iterating sequentially through all possible numbers will take much too long.

You would need to replace the smallest number of trailing digits with the missing digits while ensuring that the resulting number will be larger.  For this, the leftmost digit that you replace has to get a larger one and the rest only needs to be in increasing order (filling with extra zeros as needed):

For example:

```
def nextAllDigits(n):
    if n<=1023456789: return 1023456789     # n < 1st ==> 1st with all 10
    digits = str(n)                         # digits as string 
    missing = set("0123456789")-set(digits) # missing digits
    if not missing: return n                # none missing, n is good
    digits = "0"+digits                     # room for an extra 1
    for i,d in enumerate(digits[::-1],1):   # backward through digits
        if d not in digits[1:-i]:           # d will be replaced
            missing.add(d)                  # and will be missing 
        if i>len(missing)  and d<'9' \
        or i==len(missing) and d<max(missing):  # enough room and can increase
            if i>len(missing):
                missing.add(str(int(d)+1))      # use d+1 if extra room
            m = min(m for m in missing if m>d)  # replacement for d (greater)
            missing.discard(m)                  # no longer missing 
            zeroFill = "0"*(i-len(missing)-1)   # zeros in extra space
            return int(digits[:-i]+m+zeroFill+"".join(sorted(missing)))
            
print(nextAllDigits(9980659999))  # 10023456789

print(nextAllDigits(12345687989)) # 12345687990
```